# Slurm's srun slower than mpirun

Tags: mpi, slurm

My mpi+openmp job runs 3 times slower if in the following I replace 'mpirun' with 'srun'!

```
#!bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=locstack4d_mpi
#SBATCH --output=./res_locstack4d_mpi.txt
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100
#SBATCH --verbose
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=28

mpirun  ./locstack4d  ./locstack4d_input.dat
```

mpi implementation details:

```
Version:                                 3.1
Release Date:                            Thu Feb 20 11:41:13 CST 2014
CC:                              gcc  -m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack 
CXX:                             g++  -m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack 
F77:                             gfortran -m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack 
F90:                             gfortran -m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack 
Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--enable-sharedlibs=gcc' '--enable-shared' '--enable-lib-depend' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-fc' '--with-device=ch3:nemesis' '--with-pm=hydra:gforker' '--includedir=/usr/include/mpich-x86_64' '--bindir=/usr/lib64/mpich/bin' '--libdir=/usr/lib64/mpich/lib' '--datadir=/usr/share/mpich' '--mandir=/usr/share/man/mpich' '--docdir=/usr/share/mpich/doc' '--htmldir=/usr/share/mpich/doc' '--with-hwloc-prefix=system' 'FC=gfortran' 'F77=gfortran' 'CFLAGS=-m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -O2' 'CXXFLAGS=-m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC ' 'FCFLAGS=-m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC ' 'FFLAGS=-m64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,noexecstack ' 'MPICH2LIB_CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'MPICH2LIB_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'MPICH2LIB_FCFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'MPICH2LIB_FFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'LIBS=-lrt -lpthread ' 'CPPFLAGS= -I/builddir/build/BUILD/mpich-3.1-rh/src/mpl/include -I/builddir/build/BUILD/mpich-3.1-rh/src/mpl/include -I/builddir/build/BUILD/mpich-3.1-rh/src/openpa/src -I/builddir/build/BUILD/mpich-3.1-rh/src/openpa/src -I/builddir/build/BUILD/mpich-3.1-rh/src/mpi/romio/include'
Process Manager:                         pmi
Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
Topology libraries available:            hwloc
Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
Checkpointing libraries available:       
Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

Comment: Need details about hardware and software. Affinity may be an issue.

Comment: The small cluster of computers I am using are all of the same platform and operating system: Intel Xeon Processor E5-2640
(15M Cache, 2.50 GHz, 7.20 GT/s Intel QPI), number of cores: 6. Physical memory; 128GB. Centos Linux.

Comment: That's not detail. Needed are: CPU type. Compiler and OpenMP implantation version. OS version. MPI implementation details.

Comment: I wrote about the CPU. OS Centos 6.6. Kernel version: 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64. Compiler: gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11). OpenMP version 3.1. I edited the original post with details of MPI implementation.

Comment: How many cores per node?

Comment: @CarlesFenoy see http://ark.intel.com/m/products/64591/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2640-15M-Cache-2_50-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI

Comment: @user1641496 so you have 2x6 cores per node with 24 HW threads total and you ask for 28 OpenMP threads? And 16 CPUs per task w/ 1 task per node? This makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, it should say 2x8 cores giving 16 and hyperthreading resulting in maximum of 32 threads of which I use 28.

Answer (score 6):

Your MPI implementation does probably not use Slurm's PMI correctly, resulting in three independent 1-cpu processes being spawned rather than the expected 3-cpu job. You need to make sure the MPI version and Slurm version are compatible (for instance OpenMPI >=1.5 and Slurm >=2.6) and that OpenMPI was compiled with Slurm support (see http://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html)

Answer (score 2):

If slurm is configured with task affinity and is not aware of the HyperThreading it will not allow any job to use more cpus/cores than requested. So if you are requesting 16 cpus-per-task Slurm will limit you to that number of cpus.

Depending on the MPI implementation it is possible that the application is not bounded to the resources requested and hence it is faster than running with srun.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think what you say is indeed the case. However, when I monitor the program's run on the individual hosts in the  cluster with the "top", I see a cpu usage of 2800%, which is the number of the threads I have requested and 100% usage, for both mpirun and srun case (I only use 3 computers for this example).Stiil, srun is almost exactly 3 times slower. My code is in another stackexchange thread  (when it was still buggy but almost correct): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649447/mpi-help-on-how-to-parallelize-my-code

Comment: Considering you are using 3 nodes and slurm is 3 times slower it seems that with srun you are running 3 independent runs, while with mpirun is 1 run with 3 nodes. Can you check if that is the case running a Hello World and printing the rank id of each of the processes?